# Elementary analysis section 17, example 1

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Self-studying Elementary Analysis K. Ross, 2nd edition.

Example 1.a: Let $f(x)=2x^2+1$, prove $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb(R)$ by using the definition.
[image]

I don't follow its proof here. The definition says to prove a function is continuous, one would need to prove that *each point of $S\subseteq dom(f)$ $f$ is continuous. But in fact the book merely shows the proof by using a $lim$, by assuming $lim x = x_0$, as if that way $x_n$ would be generic enough to hold for *all* sequences. I just feel something is missing here for me.

Attaching screen shots for the definition below.

Much appreciated.
[image: Definition]

Comment: The sequence tacitly defined by $\lim x_n = x_0$ is entirely arbitrary other than it converges to $x_0$. Most of the proof happens in the step $\lim (2x_n^2 + 1) = 2(\lim  x_n)^2 + 1$ which allows us to use the convergence of the sequence to make the next substitution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative explanation:

Sequences aren't actually involved, since the domain of $f(x)$ is all of $\Bbb{R}$, rather than a set of discrete points in $\Bbb{R}$.

So, the pertinent definition of continuity is :

- A function is continuous throughout its domain if and only if the function is continuous at every point $x_0$ in its domain.
- A function is continuous at $x_0$, if and only if 
  For all $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ such that for all $x$ such that $x$ is in the domain of $f$ and $0 < |x - x_0| < \delta,$ you have that $|f(x) - f(x_0)| < \epsilon.$ 
  This can be restated as $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) = f(x_0) ~: ~x \in ~$ the domain of $f$.

Notice that in the above definition, there is no discussion about sequences.  Instead, the discussion is (effectively) about $\delta$-neighborhoods around $x_0$ and $\epsilon$-neighborhoods around $f(x_0)$.

---

Judging by the excerpted text, the problem solver is supposed to assume that the following results have already been established.

- If $f(x) = x,$ then for any value $x_0$, you have that 
  $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = x_0.$
- If $\displaystyle ~\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) ~$ exists and is finite, then 
  $\displaystyle ~\lim_{x \to x_0} \left\{ ~\left[f(x)\right]^2 ~\right\} = \left[\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)\right]^2. ~$
- If $\displaystyle ~\lim_{x \to x_0} f(x) ~$ exists and is finite, and $C$ is a constant 
  $\displaystyle ~\lim_{x \to x_0} \left\{ ~\left[f(x) + C\right] ~\right\} = \left[\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x)\right] + C. ~$

**Note**
In the above (long-winded) verbiage, the phrase *limit exists and is finite* is actually redundant.  If the limit exists, then the limit must be a finite number.  I simply used the redundant phrase for emphasis.

Comment: Thanks. This is very through. I think the gap in my understanding is exactly at the step of "This can be restated ... ".  The definition of lim is based on a "given sequence", and $\epsilon-\delta$ does not require a sequence be involved at all.   Why they are equivalent, is the missing piece for me.

Comment: @RoyHuang They are **not equivalent**.  The $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of the limit of a function that has a **continuous domain** is **different** from the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of a **sequence**.

Answer (score 0):

It is saying that $x_n$ is an arbitrary sequence that converges to $x_0$, and uses the definition that $f$ is continuous at $x_0$ if $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x_0)$. Those theorems allow the limit to be brought into the function (i.e. lim $2x^2=2(\text{lim } x)^2$. Because the choices of $x_n$ and $x_0$ were arbitrarily true, $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(x_0)$ for any choice of $x_n$ and $x_0$, proving the continuity of $f$.